# Why is orddict:fetch/2 being crazy?

Tags: erlang

At the Erlang shell:

```
> orddict:fetch(b, [{d, 2}, {a, 1}, {b,5}, {c,9}]).
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    orddict:fetch(b,[{d,2},{a,1},{b,5},{c,9}])
```

but

```
> orddict:fetch(b, [{a, 1}, {b,5}, {c,9}]).
5
```

What am I missing here?

References: [orddict:fetch/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/orddict.html#fetch-2)

[The orddict docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/orddict.html) describe an orddict as `orddict() = [{Key :: term(), Value :: term()}]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The key to the solution to this problem is in [the docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/orddict.html):

> The list is ordered after the keys.

Use [orddict:from_list/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/orddict.html#from_list-1) to convert from a regular list of `{key, value}` pairs.

```
> orddict:fetch(b, orddict:from_list([{d, 2}, {a, 1}, {b,5}, {c,9}])).
5
```